# How can I run cmake from within cmake?

Tags: cmake

My project depends on [mariadb-connector-c](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c) and I'm trying to automate the download, build and link process with cmake.

I currently download the project into a directory, I then try to execute generate ninja files and run them but I cannot run cmake at all:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "cmake -GNinja ." WORKING_DIRECTORY ${mariadb-connector-c_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I know this doesn't work because the next step, running ninja, fails:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "ninja" WORKING_DIRECTORY ${mariadb-connector-c_SOURCE_DIR})
```

cmake runs fine in CLI, I've tried using the full path to the cmake executable and replacing the dot with the variable with the full directory (which is also a valid variable, if you're wondering.)

How can I tell cmake to run cmake on that external project?

Comment: Looks like You might benefit from [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: For ExternalProject latest documentation is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can organize your project to a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` build your subprojects as [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html).

This approach requires more work and maintenance of more CMake modules but it has its own benefits. I download Google Test as follows:

```
# Create download URL derived from version number.
set(GTEST_HOME https://github.com/google/googletest/archive)
set(GTEST_DOWNLOAD_URL ${GTEST_HOME}/release-${GTEST_VERSION}.tar.gz)
unset(GTEST_HOME)

# Download and build the Google Test library and add its properties to the third party arguments.
set(GTEST_ROOT ${THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_PATH}/gtest CACHE INTERNAL "")
ExternalProject_Add(gtest
    URL ${GTEST_DOWNLOAD_URL}
    CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_GTEST=ON -DBUILD_GMOCK=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${GTEST_ROOT}
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)

list(APPEND GLOBAL_THIRDPARTY_LIB_ARGS "-DGTEST_ROOT:PATH=${GTEST_ROOT}")
unset(GTEST_DOWNLOAD_URL)
unset(GTEST_ROOT)
```

The code abowe is inside my `ExternalGoogleTest.cmake` module which is included by `CMakeLists.txt` of third-party libraries:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_BASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ThirdParty)
get_directory_property(THIRDPARTY_BASE_PATH EP_BASE)

set(THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_PATH ${THIRDPARTY_BASE_PATH}/Install)
set(GTEST_VERSION 1.8.0)

include(ExternalProject)
include(ExternalGoogleTest)
```

Your own project which depends on an external library will need a CMake module to build it as [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html) too. It can looks like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(my_project
    DEPENDS gtest whatever
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
    CMAKE_ARGS
        ${GLOBAL_DEFAULT_ARGS}
        ${GLOBAL_THIRDPARTY_LIB_ARGS}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${DESIRED_INSTALL_PATH}/my_project
    BUILD_COMMAND make
)
```

You can found more tips about this pattern [here](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/).